# Asymmetric Post dial delay

Tags: sip, voip, 3g, modem

I'm trying to measure post dial delay between IMS client with different medium transport.

What I've got is:

When caller is using *HSDPA*(up 384 kbps. down 3,6 kbps) & receiver is using *EDGE*, it has more *PDD* than caller *EDGE* and callee *HSDPA*.

Does anyone know how this could have happened?

*It has to be have the same PDD, Isn't it?*

Comment: sipwiz is probably right that the network has more to do with the delay than the Radio Access Technology, because you aren't sending huge amounts of data. If you were sending big amounts of data, you would see that HSDPA would be a lot faster when it's receiving the data. HSPDA has no extra power on the uplink, so it's not faster than UMTS for sending data. By the way, the downlink speed for HSDPA is about 3.6 Mbps, not kbps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why the PDD would be related to network transport at all. More than likely the PDD is related to whatever processing your carrier's billing and routing servers need to do before putting the call through.

If your IMS client is using SIP, as you allude to in the tags on the question, then relatively speaking the call request packet is so small that the transmission time over any network transport is likely to be negligible.

Comment: I'm guessing it's due asymmetric routing on my ISP network, but the problem is i can not find the solution yet to prove is it realy asymmetric or not.

Comment: is there a way, to trace back from my server to client behind NAt?or at least to check whether it realy asymmetric or not?